# Modular dependency blocks for multiple applications in a NodeJS package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, package.json

I have multiple applications in my main nodejs application(each having its own server and dependencies).

`server.js
- app1.js
- app2.js
- app3.js`

I want to install only selected **npm packages** corresponding to app on any server where the code is cloned. Is it possible to create **package.json** file that can have custom **app1Dependencies**, **app2Dependencies** and **app3Dependencies** apart from **dependencies** where I can install using `npm install --app1Dependencies` when I want to run only **server.js** & **app1.js**.

Comment: You could have multiple `package.json`s to swap between, but this structure generally sounds like a mistake.

Comment: It will require package.json.1, package.json.2 and so on files to be created and then renamed manually while installation which won't be a generic solution.

Comment: This is not a common way to structure Node.js projects, so there's no generic solution for what you want to do.